# Hiding files in python twisted web server

Tags: python, web, twisted

Is there any way to hide files or directories in a simple Python Twisted web server?  It's easy to serve a directory as a File resource, but I would like to filter out some files (by extension) and directories (by name, or just hide them all).

Comment: If you're using `twistd`/`twist` cli theres an `--ignore-ext` option that will ignore specified extensions. You can also pass in a `ignoredExts` into `File` object if you're running a script

Comment: My understanding is that ignoreExt is used to ignore the extension on some files.  If you set it to ".txt", and the server client asks for file "readme", they get "readme.txt" in return.  So I don't think this is what I am looking for.